# setting a whole style string to an element from javascript (not individual style parameters)

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

I need to set an arbitrary style to a span via javascript.

I know I can do things like: `span.style.height="250px"`;
But I need to be able to insert a random full style definition from a template

for example

```
float:left; 
text-decoration:underline; 
cursor:pointer; 
color:blue;
```

Is there a way to do that in Javascript? Something like:

`element.style="all style definition here";`

Comment: Comment- must be stand alone code. No jQuery or otherh libs...

Comment: Is it feasible to figure out how jQuery does it? It's fully written in js itself, so it's got to be there.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

How about the .style.cssText property? [Here's Microsoft's explanation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533698(VS.85).aspx)

Throw it the styles you'd like to apply like so:

```
document.getElementById('myEl').style.cssText = 'float:left;margin-top:75px;';
```

As for browser support, although it was IE-proprietary I believe it's well-supported (works in the IEs, FF3, and Safari 3.2 WIN at least).

Comment: FYI: Here's the [Quirksmode info on `.cssText`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#t30)

Answer (score 12):

If you want it to be lightweight, create a function such as:

```
function setStyles(element, styles)
{
    for(var s in styles) {
        element.style[s] = styles[s];
    }
}
```

Then you would pass the styles in as an object literal:

```
setStyles(element, {float: "left",
                    textDecoration: "underline",
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    color: "blue"});
```

Note that the style references passed in have to follow the naming from a JavaScript standpoint, since the function simply changes the styles by accessing the element's `style` object through JavaScript.

If you must take your style input from a string then you could quite easily parse it and create the object literal.

Answer (score 4):

There is `element.setAttribute('style', '...');`, but it fails in IE.

There is [a solution](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/setAttribute-style-IE), but I haven't tried.