# Applying css style dynamically

Tags: javascript, css

hello I extract the style attributes names from xml file  (color and font in this case )
so at the end I've got variable `style1=color` and `style2= font`;

But when I wrote the following code - it doesn't work - the programme says that `style1` is undefined. How can I change that?

```
var header=document.createElement("div");
    header.setAttribute("id", "header1");


   header.style.style1=headerstyles[i].nodeValue;
```

Comment: What is `headerstyles`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `style1` is a variable holding the actual css property name like color/font, you cannot  use the `.`(dot) operator, you need to use `[]` to specify the property.

```
header.style[style1]=headerstyles[i].nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because style itself is an object. What you want is:

header.style.setAttribute('color','red');

But IE doesn't support setAttribute for style objects.

So use the fully cross-browser supported:

header.style.cssColor = 'red';

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
header.style.color
&
header.style.fontFamily, header.style.fontSize
```

to change the styles you mentioned.

You can also use [CSS Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981619/setting-a-whole-style-string-to-an-element-from-javascript-not-individual-style)

```
header.style.cssText
```