# add break tag to show individual line using regexp

Tags: javascript

I have a div element. I will copy-paste some text in this div. Then, upon clicking a create button, another div will be created inside the div with the selected text inside it. The new div will have a different background-color, different fonts, and other style properties.**My problem here is i want each line will be a seperate individual line .so i use replace() command and regexp to change evere semi-colon with a  tag.but it is considering tag part of the string and no individual line is created**.how can it be solved

This is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/kmLfF/).

JS

```
function changeit() {
    var slctn = document.getSelection();
    var strings = slctn.toString();
    alert(strings);
    var get_id = document.getElementById("myspace");
    var elem = document.createElement("div");
    var design = document.createAttribute("style");
    design.value = "background-color:grey;color:black;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;font-family:CURSIVE;";
    elem.setAttributeNode(design);

    alert("it is done");

    var rep = strings.replace(/\;/g, "<br>");
    var texts = document.createTextNode(rep);

    alert(texts);
    elem.appendChild(texts);
    get_id.appendChild(elem);
}
```

HTML

```
<div  contenteditable="true" width="40px" height="50px" style="display:block;" id="myspace">ddd</div>
<input type="button" value="select" onClick="changeit();">
```

Comment: Does the style actually work that way? Normally you use cssText http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981619/setting-a-whole-style-string-to-an-element-from-javascript-not-individual-style

Comment: You are creating a textNode, they do not have breaks.

Comment: then how can it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace like this:

```
// elem.appendChild(texts);
elem.innerHTML = rep;
```

Here is the working example on **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nEdLt/)**

Comment: would you pls tell me why elem.innerHTML works but my code doesn't?

Comment: **createTextNode()** does exactly what it is expected - creates text from the provided string. When appended to an element it acts like such. With **innerHTML** you're explicitly telling the elemnent that this is html you want to display and should be parsed as such.